# How to scroll within a div with jQuery animate() function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code snippet which scrolls the entire body to a particular location →

```
$('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: 1000}, 800, 'swing');
```

But what if i want to scroll to a particular location within a div like this →

```
$('#div-id').animate({ scrollTop: 1000}, 800, 'swing');
```

I tried this way but its not working, can you tell me where i am going wrong?

NOTE: The element `#div-id` has overflow:auto as one of its css rule.

Comment: Is the div scrollable? `overflow-y: scroll;`?

Comment: The plugin for which I asked this question is now being used by many developers, may be worth a look: http://plugins.compzets.com/animatescroll/

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Try this demo:

```js
$('#div').scroll();
$("#div").animate({
  scrollTop: 1000
}, 2000);
```

```css
#div {
  height: 100px;
  overflow: scroll;
  width: 200px;
  border: 2px solid red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
  <div id='div'>
    dads dads dads dadsdads dadsdads dadsdads dadsdads dadsdads dadsdads dads dads dadsdads dadsdads dadsdads dadsdads dadsdads dadsdads dads dads dadsdads dadsdads dadsdads dadsdads dadsdads dadsdads dads dads dadsdads dadsdads dadsdads dadsdads dadsdads
    dadsdads dads dads dadsdads dadsdads dadsdads dadsdads dadsdads dadsdads dads dads dadsdads dadsdads dadsdads dadsdads dadsdads dadsdads dadsdads dadsdads dadsdads dadsdads dadsdads dadsdads dadsdads dads dads dadsdads dadsdads dadsdads dadsdads dadsdads
    dadsdads dadsdads dadsdads dadsdads dadsdads dadsdads dadsdads dadsdads dads
  </div>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, this works for me but i don't understand why you call the scroll() function and then again animate(), it can be done directly with animate() i guess

Comment: for nice look and user a easy to understand it what happen on it

Answer (score 10):

How about trying like this:-

```
function scrollingdiv(parentid, id){
    $("#"+parentid).animate({scrollTop: $("#"+id).position().top}, 800, 'swing');
}
```