# Add smooth-vertical scrolling within specific div overflow, via buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, buttonclick, smooth-scrolling

I have a div on my site which is populated with blogs from an RSS feed. On the top and bottom, are buttons to scroll up and down within the div (as it has hidden overflow for extra blogs). I'm wondering what I need to add, in order to make this a smooth scroll, rather than just snap-scrolling on click.

HTML:

```
<div class="col-md-4 hidden-xs hidden-sm" id="blogSection">
    <div class="row" id="scrollUp">
        <button id="downClick"><i class="fa fa-chevron-up fa-2x"></i></button>
    </div>
    <!-- ------------ BLOGS RSS FEED POPULATED ------------- -->    
    <div id="homeBlogs">
        <script language="JavaScript" src="http://feed2js.org//feed2js.php?src=http%3A%2F%2Fblogs.msbcollege.edu%2Ffeed%2F&chan=y&desc=250>1&targ=y&utf=y"  charset="UTF-8" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <noscript>
        <a href="http://feed2js.org//feed2js.php?src=http%3A%2F%2Fblogs.msbcollege.edu%2Ffeed%2F&chan=y&desc=250>1&targ=y&utf=y&html=y">View RSS feed</a>
        </noscript>
    </div>
    <!-- END RSS POPULATION ---------- -->
    <div class="row" id="scrollDown">
        <button id="upClick"><i class="fa fa-chevron-down fa-2x"></i></button>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {


$("#upClick").click(function() {
    $('#homeBlogs').scrollTop($('#homeBlogs').scrollTop() + 200);
  });

  $("#downClick").click(function() {
    $('#homeBlogs').scrollTop($('#homeBlogs').scrollTop() - 200);
  });

});
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using jQuery, you are probably looking for the jQuery animate library:

```
var scrollTime = 2000;

$('#upClick').click(function() {
    $('#homeBlogs').animate({
        scrollTop: $('#homeBlogs').scrollTop() + 200
    }, scrollTime);
});


$('#downClick').click(function() {
    $('#homeBlogs').animate({
        scrollTop: $('#homeBlogs').scrollTop() - 200
    }, scrollTime);
});
```

Comment: Hey thanks, I believe the animate library is just what I need. After trying your provided code in place of what I had, button click had no effect. Any ideas? It may be another chunk of my JS file as well.

Comment: Perhaps you need `$('#div').scroll();` before using animate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18545467/how-to-scroll-within-a-div-with-jquery-animate-function