# scroll with anchor without # in URL for bootstrap modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I have read this [SO Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15223006/scroll-with-anchor-without-in-url) and applied the code to my pages and it works well.

However, I have the page help details displayed in a [bootstrap modal](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals). When the user clicks on the page help icon, the bootstrap modal opens and displays the help details. I have a "top" button on the bootstrap modal help so that the user can scroll to the top of the bootstrap modal help "page".

The issue I have is that the scroll up to the top of the bootstrap modal help "page" does not occur. Instead, the actual page that the bootstrap modal was initiated from scrolls up.

**How do I amend my code so that the scrolling effect will occur on the bootstrap modal?**

Here is my js code:

```
function goToByScrollHelp(id){
    $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: $("#"+id).offset().top},'slow');
}
```

Here is my html code link:

```
<a id="id_top_of_help"></a>
```

Comment: Shouldn't `animate` be applied to `$(".modal")` instead of `html` and `body`? If yes, refer this to achieve the same - http://stackoverflow.com/a/18545620/4719761

Comment: Of course! Yes that is the solution. Thank you.