# Animate scroll when button taped

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Good Evening,

I have been trying to animate a scroll-feature when tapping on a button. Below you will find the code that isn't working, my question is why.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('a[href="#panel-body"]').on('click', function (event) {
    if(this.hash !== "") {
        event.preventDefault();
        var hash = this.hash;

        $("html, body").animate({
            scrollTop: $(hash).offset().top
        }, 800 function () {
            window.location.hash = hash;
        });
    }
});
});
```

I have assigned a link with the href="#panel-body". Tried with different variants and searched for a solution, still haven't managed to solve it.

Thanks for the help in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found out that you want to create Up Going Button, For do this use the code below :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('button').click(function () {
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: '0px'
        }, 750);
    });     
});
```

Comment: Thanks Ali for your answer. This worked great if I wanted the button to scroll  up, how about if I want it to animate scroll going down to the element with id="panel-body"?

Comment: Your Welcome, It is exactly what you want, So I don't repeat it :) :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18545467/how-to-scroll-within-a-div-with-jquery-animate-function

Comment: Excellent ... :))